# How to avoid the error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' what(): basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

Tags: c++, libstdc++

```
if(player!=NULL)
    player->shuffled();
```

I do such things to avoid passing a null reference to a string constructor, but when compiling it still comes to error.

Comment: You should post more context.

Comment: What's the stack trace from the exception?

Comment: The stack trace never gives anything useful for this, it's all internal c++ libraries that doesn't relate in any way to the user's source code. Otherwise yes, there wouldn't be 56k views for this question in 10 months!

Answer (score 89):

Somewhere, somehow, you're calling the `std::string` constructor with the `const char*` value NULL.

To avoid the problem.  Don't do that.

Comment: I was trying `string cmd = argv[1]` when no argument was given, so smart.