# basic_string::_S_construct null not valid error while sending std::string in function argument/socket

Tags: c++

Here I am trying to send string into function argument and as a parameter in socket using send() method.

user_main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    const char *buffer;
    const char *ch;
    std::string input = argv[2];
    int ar[2];
    printf("Client : \n");
    if ( argc != 2 ) /* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
    {
              printf( "\n%s filename\n", argv[0] );
    }
    else 
    {       
    ch=client(input);
    ar[0]=((int*)ch)[0];
    ar[1]=((int*)ch)[1];

    }

    printf("\n @ar[0]=%d;ar[1]=%d@ \n",ar[0],ar[1]);
    return ar[1];
}
```

client.cpp:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwrite-strings"

int ar[10];
char *client(std::string input_string)
{
    //Process user inserted data. Remove punctuation marks from input_string
    std::replace_if(input_string.begin(), input_string.end(), 
                 std::ptr_fun<int, int>(&std::ispunct), ' ');

    int host_port= 1103;
    char* host_name="127.0.0.1";

    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
    int bytecount; 
    int buffer_len=0;
    int i=0,x=0;
    int hsock;
    int * p_int;
    int err;
    hsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(hsock == -1){
        printf("Error initializing socket %d\n",errno);
        goto FINISH;
    }

    p_int = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p_int = 1;

    if( (setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1 )||
        (setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1 ) ){
        printf("Error setting options %d\n",errno);
        free(p_int);
        goto FINISH;
    }
    free(p_int);

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;  my_addr.sin_port = htons(host_port);     

    memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host_name);

    if( connect( hsock, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) == -1 ){
        if((err = errno) != EINPROGRESS){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting socket %d\n", errno);
            goto FINISH;
        }
    }

    if( (bytecount=send(hsock, input_string.c_str(), input_string.length(),0))== -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data %d\n", errno);
        goto FINISH;
    }
    if((bytecount = recv(hsock, ar, sizeof(ar), 0))== -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data %d\n", errno);
        goto FINISH;
    }
     x= sizeof(ar)/sizeof(int);
    printf("x is %d: \n ",x);
    for(i=0; i < (sizeof(ar)/sizeof(*ar));i++)
    {
        std::cout << ar[i] << std::endl;
    }

    close(hsock);

FINISH:
;
//printf("array item2 %d \n",ar[1]);
return (char *)ar;
}
```

client.h

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef client_h__
#define client_h__
extern char *client(std::string string_input);

#endif
```

It compiles correct, but while I run it gives error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I saw solution for this error : [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705886/how-to-avoid-the-error-terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-stdlog). But here I nowhere  calling the std::string constructor with the const char* value NULL. Or I dont know. please let me know where I am making mistake.

Comment: if  you pass less 2 arguments, `std::string input = argv[2];` will fail before you check argc. should put this after `if ( argc != 2 )`

Comment: @billz: thanks, that was one of the mistake. First I compile: g++ -o b user_main.cpp client.cpp then `./b "one one two"'. But yet it run till half way only!

Comment: which `ar` should you use?

Comment: In which file you talking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like :

`std::string input = argv[2];`

should be

`std::string input = argv[1];`

inside

```
else { 

}
```

in `main`

Also,

you should be running your program like : (considering `user_main` as your executable)

`user_main HelloWorld`

or

`user_main "This is;! string with;'punctuations!"`

Comment: thanks, that was one of the mistake. First I compile: `g++ -o b user_main.cpp client.cpp` then `./b "one one two"'. But yet it run till half way only!

Comment: I have edited the code, if you would like to compile then it will work on your system also, just in case if you can test it!

Comment: @Karimkhan nah..I don't have system as of now, but what's "half way" ?
Is same error throwing again ?

Comment: No no error. It sends the string but does not do any action after that. actually it should show result received from server.process

Comment: I checked it, I think problem is after `recv()' operation. Before that when I printed msg then it was working and showing on prompt!