# std::logic_error: basic_string::_s_construct null not valid

Tags: c++

I am getting `std::logic_error: basic_string::_s_construct null not valid` in this program. How can I solve that? I already tried a [previously posted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705886/how-to-avoid-the-error-terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-stdlog) but could not correct it myself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     stack<string> s;
     string temp, exp[] = "abc-+de-fg-h+/*";
     string ch1 = 0, ch2 = 0, ch = 0;
     int sizeExp = sizeof(exp)/sizeof(*exp);
     for(int i=0; i < sizeExp ; i++) {
         ch = exp[i];
         if (ch == "*" || ch == "/" || ch == "+" || ch == "-") {
             if (s.empty() && sizeof(temp) != sizeof(exp)) {
                 cout << "Error in Expression." << endl;
             }
             else {
                 if (sizeof(s.top()) != sizeof(char)){
                     ch1 = s.top();
                     s.pop();
                     ch2 = s.top();
                     temp = '(' + ch2 + ')' + exp[i] + '(' + ch1 + ')';
                     s.push(temp);
                 }
                 else {
                     ch1 = s.top();
                     s.pop();
                     ch2 = s.top();
                     temp = ch2 + exp[i] + ch1;
                     s.push(temp);
                 }
             }
         }
         else {
             s.push(exp[i]);
         }
     }
     cout << temp << endl << "Is your Infix Expression for ";
     cout << exp;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: which previous solution were you referencing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705886/how-to-avoid-the-error-terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-stdlog

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is with statements of the sort `std::string str = 0;`. This leads to undefined behaviour. Use `std::string str = "";` to create empty strings.

`std::string str = 0;` resolves to the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) `std::string::string(const char* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())`. The behaviour of this constructor is undefined when `s` is `nullptr`. Your argument of `0` gets converted to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for `std::string` clearly states that you shall not construct one from a null pointer. Yet, here you are, doing just that!

```
string ch1 = 0, ch2 = 0, ch = 0;  // BAD
string ch1, ch2, c;               // Substantially better
```

Comment: To be fair, the meaning of `string ch1 = 0;` could be far from obvious to a beginner. Actually, the fact that this even compiles can very well be considered a flaw of the language. If only `nullptr` had been there all along... :)